# Logging DTCs for later analysis

Tags: capl

I am new to CAPL and trying to read DTCs periodically using CAPL script and log them to .blf file so they can be analyzed later.

After some research I decided to store all read and identified DTCs to system variable (which I defined as integer array `dtcArr` with fixed size of 500) as a way to output read DTCs, since system variables are logged also when the logging is started and can be shown from the logs later. Simply using `write` command to output it to file doesn't help much since that can't be shown in CANalyzer/CANoe on analysis later if I got that right. Basically I'm filling up `dtcArr` with all read DTCs values in order I read them.

Seems that using associative arrays for system variables is not possible (e.g. using DTC name text as a key), is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Just log the CAN messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy to achieve.  You need a script in the output loop, which makes DTC read requests to the target module.  It must also handles any continuation frames that need to be sent:

```
variables
{
  msTimer         can1_ms_timer;
  long            ms_interval = 1000; /* Request rate */
  message CAN1.*  can1_dtc_req_frame = {id=???, dir=tx, byte(0)=0x??, byte(1)=0x??, byte(2)=0x??, etc.};
}

on key ctrlF1
{
  write("Starting Read DTC Information from module ???");
  setTimer(can1_ms_timer, ms_interval);
}

on timer can1_ms_timer
{
  output(can1_dtc_req_frame);
  setTimer(can1_ms_timer, ms_interval);
}

on message CAN1.ResponseModule???
{
  /* Handle sending continuation frame */

  output(this);
}
```

Now the modules responses shall be stored in the logging file, and you can processes them any way you choose.  For my setup, I have a second CAPL script which converts trouble codes to my own custom CAN signals so I can plot their status values in the graph view.

```
on message CAN1.ResponseModule???
{
  /* Process trouble code response */
}
```